# Office Interop PowerPoint E_NOINTERFACE registry fault

Tags: c#, .net, interop, powerpoint-2010

**Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to event interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PresEvents_Event'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{9826398E-2574-3EDD-9717-A913EE28A41D}' failed due to the following error: 'No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))' and the COM component does not support the source interface with IID '{91493463-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B}'.**

I have two smilar website that convert PPTX to pdf. They use same code and same dlls for operation. One site used like proff of concept and experimental but other is for commercial.

Experiamental one works perfectly but other one has fault.

I use same code same dll but it never works

Two of sites run on same application pool.

code for convert is :

```
var powerpointApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

var powerpointDocument = powerpointApp.Presentations.Open(@"C:\PowerPoint.pptx", 
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, //ReadOnly
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, //Untitled
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse); //Window not visible during converting

powerpointDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(@"C:\NewPDFFile.pdf", 
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType.ppFixedFormatTypePDF);

powerpointDocument.Close(); //Close document
powerpointApp.Quit();
```

**Stack Trace:**

> System.StubHelpers.InterfaceMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr pUnk,
>   IntPtr itfMT, IntPtr classMT, Int32 flags) +0
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations.Open(String
>   FileName, MsoTriState ReadOnly, MsoTriState Untitled, MsoTriState
>   WithWindow) +0
>   AB.Hybrid.WebSite.Controllers.ViewerController.tryConvert() +157
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +156
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9651796    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem's actual reason is based on interop dlls.

> I changed "Embed Interop Types to False" from PowerPoint dll
>   refenrance properties

finally it worked like a charm

I guess two or more project used same dll with embed option cause to colision on

registry referance on windows and second one try to register new key then get

fault like mine

I hope it helps